# How to change schema of crawled table while running the AWS glue job

Tags: aws-glue

Created a glue ETL job using pyspark in where output in s3 was only .csv and .csv.gz along with glue crawler later we created a test pipline with same logic but this time output in parquet format but the tables which was created by crawler had change in schema like bigint changed to string , double changed to float.
how I can set particular data type in crawled table while job is running ?
Also do parquet change the schema?

I dont want to change the schema to table it should remain what it was in original pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

For CSV files, it's the crawler responsibility to infer schema. However, for Parquet files, column data type is defined as metadata together with the file.

In your Glue ETL job, check the schema by

```
dynf.printSchema()
```

You can rename fields and change field types using [apply_mapping()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-apply_mapping)

Comment: this piece code reads data  from catalog then set its schema  but in my case I have to change the schema of already existed Glue crawler table.